# SSH tunnel to remote docker service

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose

I have a server with several Docker services ran by `docker-compose`. Database service looks like this:

```
myproject_influxdb:                                    
  container_name: myproject_influxdb
  image: 'influxdb:alpine'
  volumes:                                        
   - '/var/lib/influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb'
   - './influxdb.conf:/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf'
  ports:
   - '8086:8086'
```

It can be accessed by `myproject_influxdb:8086` from other containers.

Now I want to connect to that database from my local docker service. I run `ssh -L 8086:localhost:8086 user@host` in a new terminal. Then I try to connect to remote `myproject_influxdb` service but no matter what host I enter (`localhost`, `myproject_influxdb`, `0.0.0.0`) I get same error: `[Errno 111] Connection refused`.

Is it because both remote and host services are not using `network_mode: "host"`?

Comment: `influxdb:alpine` does not have ssh installed.

Comment: @joppich I don't see any reason to have ssh inside influxdb container. Why should it have it?

Comment: sorry, i misread. i thought you wanted to jumphost into the container. does creating the tunnel with `ssh -NL 8086:localhost:8086 [...]` help?

Answer (score 1):

`docker-compose` services are on different network than standard `docker run` containers.

That is why the `myproject_influxdb` wont work. If you are inside docker container and try to access something with `localhost` you are just inside the same container (not the host). With that being said you can access the influxdb via the exposed port on host with

```
host_ip:8086
```

to get the ip address of host you can use this bash command

```
/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }'
```

Comment: Hello @MazelTov, thank you for the reply. Tunnel is running and I can do `curl -G http://localhost:8086/query` from my host machine. I get correct response. However, if I do it from inside a container (with host ip address): `curl -G http://172.19.0.1:8086/query` I get this: `Failed to connect to 172.19.0.1 port 8086: Connection refused`.

Comment: can you provide output of `docker ps` and how you start your container

Comment: could you also try `nc -z 172.19.0.1 8086 -v` from your container, that way you could tell if the port is open... maybe the influxdb is configured to listen only on specific interfaces....

Comment: Container that I want to connect to remote influxdb from is called api:
`14b0737dcf87        myproject_myproject_api               "./entrypoint.sh"        4 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:3031->3031/tcp                             myproject_api`. It is started by `docker-compose`. Network is default.

Answer (score 1):

Two option:

1) Use `--network=host` to run your container locally like so

```
docker run -it --rm --network=host -p 8888:8888 chronograf --influxdb-url=http://localhost:8086
```

However this does give your container access to your entire host network, which raises security vulnerabilities.

2) You could to connect the tunnel to your local Docker bridge network and then tell your local docker container to use the bridge's IP as well.

You can get your local bridge IP address with either `ip addr` or `docker network inspect bridge`

After that your ssh command would be

`ssh -L <bridge-ip>:8086:localhost:8086 user@host`

If, like me, you were trying to run chronograf locally, this shell script would do it for you.

```
#! /usr/bin/env sh
echo "Retrieving BRIDGE IP"
BRIDGE_IP=$(docker network inspect --format '{{(index .IPAM.Config 0).Gateway}}' bridge)
echo "Found BRIDGE_IP: ${BRIDGE_IP}"
ssh -NL ${BRIDGE_IP}:8086:127.0.0.1:8086 <user>@<host> &
PID=$!
echo "Saved SSH PID: ${PID}"
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 chronograf --influxdb-url=http://${BRIDGE_IP}:8086
kill $PID
echo "Done ..."
```